# Mongoosejs, how to save array of strings coming from the request body as an array of objectId?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongoose, express

I'm having troubles while trying to handle arrays of objectIds (for further population in mongoosejs models), I hope you can help me. here is the context:

I have a little nodejs / angularjs app where I have products and providers. The products have a property providers which is an array of objectId's, referencing providers. Here is the schema:

```
var productSchema = new Schema({

    name            : { type: String, required: true, trim: true},
    providers       : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'provider' }]
});
```

The user is able to query the list of providers through the GUI. Then he can select which provider are available for each product (checkboxes). Internally it means that I am pushing the hex strings corresponding to the providers _id into the array providers of my angular product model, then the request is sent to the nodejs/express server.

Here is the problem, I've been trying to turn the hex strings into objectId in many ways, I just can't find the right way. My last attempt was with the "presave" function of mongoose. Here the current version.

```
productSchema.pre('save', function (next) {

    var err = new Error('There was an error when trying to add the providers id as objectId'),
    i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < this.providers.length; i++) {

        this.providers[i] = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(this.providers[i].toString())
    }

    next(err);
});
```

Any help is welcome, I thought mongoose would just handle everything alone. What's the normal way to do this? (the pre save was just an idea)

Thanks for reading

Comment: Mongoose will do the casting from string to ObjectId for you, so something else must be amiss.  Can you post a minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Thinking about your comment, maybe it is related to array serialization, I'll post some update when I work on this again. Thank you